# Use Ivy API to obtain latest version of a dependency?

Tags: java, versioning, ivy, dependency-management

We have a simple Ivy repository we host off of an in-house server (Apache httpd serving up JARs and their XML Ivy descriptors).

I now have a need to programmatically determine what the latest version of a dependency is in our repo. Thus if we have two versions of Mockito, our repo might look like:

```
mockito/                       ==>    organisation
    mockito-all                ==>    module
        1.9.4/                 ==>    revision #
            mockito-all-1.9.4.jar
            mockito-all-1.9.4-ivy.xml
        1.9.5/
            mockito-all-1.9.5.jar
            mockito-all-1.9.5-ivy.xml
```

It would be nice if, from Java, I can use Ivy to determine that "1.9.5" is the latest version of the `mockito/mockito-all` module that we have.

This would likely not be an Ant task, and instead would likely be some custom Java code using the classes that exist inside `ivy.jar`.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use `latest.integration` revision value to specify the absolute latest version needed.  For example, specify your Ivy dependency like so:

```
<dependency org="mockito" name="mockito-all" rev="latest.integration" />
```

You can also specify `latest.milestone` or `latest.release` if you don't want the "edge" version.  Here is a good explanation on the `rev` value: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/dependency.html

Comment: Thanks @Polaris8787, but I'm not talking about at buildtime. I need to build a Java tool that will scan our Ivy repo and tell me the latest version number of each module, and then put together a custom report on it. So I need to invoke some Ivy tasks directly inside of Java code, and then use the Ivy API to get the version number as a string.

Comment: @user1768830 Did you get this done? I am looking for something similar. I do not want Ivy to just use "the latest". I want to specify every version manually, but I want a report that says "a new revision of SomeJar is available", so I can decide whether to upgrade. Ivy already gets this info in order to resolve dynamic specifications such as "0.0+" - I just want it delivered to me so I can make a decision.

Answer (score 0):

So I found your question looking to do the same thing and after some research found that in Ivy 2.4, such a thing exists.

http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/checkdepsupdate.html

Here is a sample step:

```
<target name="ivy.outdated" description="Check ivy for outdated jars">
    <ivy:resolve/>
    <ivy:checkdepsupdate showTransitive="false" revisionToCheck="latest.release"/>
</target>
```